# Splitting a CLOB column using Derived (Virtual) columns

Tags: oracle, plsql

Using Derived Columns to automatically split Large Columns

Our table has a CLOB column. The problem is whenever UI or any application tries to pull this column, it has to be first split into smaller chunks ( since Oracle limits VARCHAR2 to 4000 ).

Does it makes sense to use Virtual (Derived) columns to automatically split CLOB column into 4k segments ( as shown below ).

Thus - any application can simply query say seg_1 if it wants only first 4k chars. Or seg_1 + seg_2 and so on. ( assume here our data is only 8k )

```
create table code_text2 
( 
      text_clob    clob,
      seg_1        varchar2 (4000 byte) generated always as (substrb
                               (text_clob, 1, 4000)) virtual,
      seg_2        varchar2 (4000 byte) generated always as (substrb (text_clob, 4001, 4000)) virtual 
);
```

Comment: First of all in PL SQL VARCHAR2 maximum size is 32767 bytes, then PL SQL allows to handle clobs by itselt (CLOB type). Finally in jdbc you have the java.sql.Clob. Why to split text_clob?

Comment: That strikes me as perhaps the wrong solution to the problem. Every popular client I can think of (Java, .Net, Python, etc) have drivers that can handle clobs coming from the database. You should not have to piece it out into varchars

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  If you are using Oracle 12.1 or later, you can set `max_string_size` to `EXTENDED` to get 32k strings rather than 4000 byte strings.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-D424D23B-0933-425F-BC69-9C0E6724693C.htm#REFRN10321

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that this is not the correct approach. You should figure out what in your UI or driver or whatever that's preventing you from properly retrieving a `CLOB`.

If a client really does only care about the first 4000 characters in a `CLOB` (though I can't think why a client would want that), they can do:

```
select dbms_lob.substr( mylob, 4000, 1 ) ...
```

I don't think you should be using `SUBSTRB` with `CLOBs`, since they are character data. What happens if your 4000th character is 2-bytes wide? It would get corrupted.

Comment: The database is 12.1 which has 32,767 as length of PL/SQL VARCHAR2.

    But our client applications have different needs. 

     - Some want first 4000 bytes only
     - Some want entire 32767 
     - Others have no problem retrieving a CLOB

As suggested above - though each client can do something similar to ( dbms_lob.substr( mylob, 4000, 1 ), I want to provide a wrapper to make everybody's life easier.

Perhaps an overloaded function with different arguments can be provided and make the entire underlying implementation transparent.

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Just my opinion, I think it's a bad idea. You already have that interface, it's `substr` and `dbms_lob`. Let the client application decide what it wants and request that with a SQL query.